# Xamarin Forms CollectionView with SwipeView on items - tapping ImageButton selects cell

Tags: xamarin.forms, imagebutton, collectionview

I have an `ImageButton` in every cell in my `CollectionView`. When I tap on the `ImageButton` I expect it to capture the touch event and handle it, however it also passes the touch event up to the cell and selects that cell in the `CollectionView`.

Tapping the call changes the `SelectedItem` and opens the detail page for that contact. Tapping the `ImageButton` starts a call, but immediately switches to the detail page.

Here is a screenshot of the page:
[image: Contacts Page]

The `CollectionView` is defined as:

```
<CollectionView
    x:Name="contactsList"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedContact, Mode=TwoWay}"
    ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
    IsGrouped="True"
    EmptyView="No Contacts">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        ...
    </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <SwipeView
                x:DataType="models:Contact">
                ...
                <StackLayout
                    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}">
                    <Grid
                        Padding="0,15,0,10"
                        ColumnDefinitions="80,*,80"
                        RowDefinitions="*,*"
                        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}">
                        <Ellipse
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.RowSpan="2"
                            Fill="{Binding Colour, Converter={StaticResource intToBrushColor}}"
                            .../>
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.RowSpan="2"
                            Text="{Binding Initials}"
                            .../>
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Text="{Binding FullName}"
                            .../>
                        <StackLayout
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image
                                HeightRequest="15"
                                Source="{Binding WasOutgoing, Converter={StaticResource callDirectionToIcon}}"/>
                            <Label
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Text="{Binding TimeStamp}"
                                .../>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <ImageButton
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.RowSpan="2"
                            Margin="0,0,15,0"
                            Padding="10"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            Source="{StaticResource IconCalls}"
                            Command="{Binding BindingContext.CallCommand, Source={x:Reference contactsPage}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <BoxView
                        Style="{StaticResource Seperator}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </SwipeView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

How do I make the `ImageButton` keep the touch event and stop the cell from being selected when the `ImageButton` is tapped?

Here are a few dirty workarounds I considered but these are not ideal:

- Split the cell into two `Grid`s and have two `TapGestureRecognizer`s.
- Track if the `ImageButton` was tapped and ignore the next selection change.

These are not ideal, will cost more and break MVVM pattern. The root cause of this issue is the `ImageButton` not keeping the touch event or marking it as handled.

Does anyone know a cleaner solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've narrowed your problem down to use of `SwipeView`, in `ItemTemplate`. This seems to force the item to be selected.

Without it, works as intended.

I infer that SwipeView alters touch events, to force row selection, in order to perform its action.

See **WORKAROUND** below, for a hack fix.

---

xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <CollectionView
            x:Name="contactsList"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedContact, Mode=TwoWay}"
            ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems" >
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!--<SwipeView>-->
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Grid
                            Padding="0,15,0,10"
                            ColumnDefinitions="*,80">
                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="abcdef" />
                                <Button
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Padding="4"
                                Text="Press Me"
                                Clicked="Button_Clicked"
                                />
                            </Grid>
                        </StackLayout>
                    <!--</SwipeView>-->
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

xaml.cs:

```
public partial class CollectionViewWithCellButtonPage : ContentPage
{
    private Model selectedContact;

    public CollectionViewWithCellButtonPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public ObservableCollection<Model> Contacts { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Model> {
        new Model(),
        new Model(),
        new Model(),
    };

    public Model SelectedContact {
        get => selectedContact;
        set => selectedContact = value;
    }
}
```

---

With breakpoints on `SelectedContact` setter, and on `Button_Clicked`, a click on button does not affect `SelectedContact`. Click elsewhere on row does. This is the desired behavior.

Then uncomment `<SwipeView>` and `</SwipeView>`.

Now, `SelectedContact` setter is called. BEFORE `Button_Clicked`.
Because the call is BEFORE, I don't see any easy fix.

Fixing this "right" probably requires custom renderer (per platform) for `SwipeView`.

---

**WORKAROUND**

Got it to work. But this is a hack.

1. Delay action taken when SelectContact. This gives us time to find out if Button was pushed. (Step 2 will show _suppressSelection getting set.)

```
    private Model _selectedContact;
    private bool _suppressSelection;

    public Model SelectedContact
    {
        get => _selectedContact;
        set
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                await DelayedSetSelectedContact(value);
            });

        }
    }

    private async Task DelayedSetSelectedContact(Model value)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);

        if (_suppressSelection)
        {
            // Button was pressed. DO NOTHING - DON'T select the item.

            // Clear state for next time.
            _suppressSelection = false;
        }
        else
        {
            _selectedContact = value;
            // ... Do your other work here ...
        }
    }
```

2. Button click sets _suppressSelection. Make sure _suppressSelection can't get "stuck on".

```
    private System.Timers.Timer _buttonTimer;

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        // Make sure _suppressSelection can't get "stuck on".
        _buttonTimer = new System.Timers.Timer { Interval = 500, AutoReset = false };
        _buttonTimer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // FIRST LINE in method - do this as early as possible.
        _suppressSelection = true;

        //... your main logic here ...

        // Make sure _suppressSelection can't get "stuck on".
        _buttonTimer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // "if" line can be commented out. I just have it so breakpoint on following line is only hit if
        // timer is needed to do its job. Some sequences of item selection and button presses do hit that breakpoint.
        if (_suppressSelection)
            _suppressSelection = false;
    }
```

3. Clean up when leave page.

```
    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();

        // Stop timer. Release reference.
        if (_buttonTimer != null)
        {
            _buttonTimer.Stop();
            _buttonTimer = null;
        }
        // Clean up state, in case navigate back to page.
        _suppressSelection = false;
    }
```

---

Full code in `CollectionViewWithCellButtonPage` in [ToolmakerSteve - repo XFormsSOAnswers](https://github.com/ToolmakerSteve/XFormsSOAnswers).